# Rendering to render target makes some of my graphics invisible

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi I have been playing with render targets but I ran into some problems. I created a simplified example here:

```js
init = function() {

  // RENDERER

  canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1.0);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

  // SCENE

  texscene = new THREE.Scene();

  texcamera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );
  texcamera.position.z = 2;

  // FRAMEBUFFER

  var renderTargetParams = {
    minFilter:THREE.LinearFilter,
    stencilBuffer:false,
    depthBuffer:false,
    wrapS: THREE.RepeatWrapping,
    wrapT: THREE.RepeatWrapping       
  };
  rendertarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget( 512, 512, renderTargetParams );

  // CUBE

  var cubeGeo = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 );
  var cubeMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );
  texcube = new THREE.Mesh( cubeGeo, cubeMat )
  texscene.add(texcube);

  var blueMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0x7074FF})
  var plane = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry( 100, 100 );
  var planeObject = new THREE.Mesh(plane,blueMaterial);
  planeObject.position.z = -15;
  texscene.add(planeObject);

  /////////////////////////////////

  //SCENE

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000 );

  var boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map:rendertarget.texture});
  var boxGeometry2 = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 5, 5, 5 );
  mainBoxObject = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry2,boxMaterial);

  // Move it back so we can see it
  mainBoxObject.position.z = -10;
  // Add it to the main scene
  scene.add(mainBoxObject);

  animate();   
}

animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  renderer.render(texscene, texcamera, rendertarget);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  texcube.rotation.y += 0.01;
  texcube.rotation.z += 0.01;

  mainBoxObject.rotation.x +=0.01;
  mainBoxObject.rotation.y += 0.005;
  mainBoxObject.rotation.z += 0.008;
}

init();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.js"></script>
```

I render a red cube and a blue plane to a render target then use it as a texture. Problem is the red cube is not visible in the final result.

Try for yourself to see the render target scene by changing

```
renderer.render(texscene, texcamera, rendertarget);
renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

to
    renderer.render(texscene, texcamera);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly the problem is caused by turning off the depth buffer as I had done in the settings of my rendertarget

```
    depthBuffer:false,
```

Removing this line makes my rendertarget render as it should with a red box on a blue background

Comment: You also probably want to set the aspect ratio of `texcamera` to the aspect ratio of the rendertarget.